# Android - Conversion to Dalvik format failed

Tags: android, dalvik

I have been on this for three days now trying to figure out why I am getting this error. The project shows no errors, all libraries have been added, sdk updated, etc. However upon running the application I get Conversion to Dalvik format failed error 1. I am posting the full error for reference to anyone who can help. I think it might have something to do with google-play-services_lib but again I could be completely off. The same exact application and project setups work on two computers, but after even attempting fresh installs of adt in two other computers the same error persisted...

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVParserTest) does not match path (target/test-classes/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVParserTest.class)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:520)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:187)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:786)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:597)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:726)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:321)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:396)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1116)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:147)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1047)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1251)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
...while parsing target/test-classes/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVParserTest.class

[2013-12-26 10:02:52 - ODK Collect] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2013-12-26 10:02:52 - ODK Collect] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

[image]

Comment: From the mesage, it seems like at least one of the  `ODL Collect`-folders in the classpath contain a wrong hirarchy: there is a `target` folder with a `test-classes` subfolder which interfere with the way class files are expected. If you need the test classes, add the `test-classes` folder directly to the classpath; if you don't try to exclude them. As I don't know your project's structure nor ODK Collect, I doubt I can deliver a concrete solution though.

Comment: Change Android Target to 19 from the Android Tab in the above image

Comment: thanks for the response, but same error still persists

Comment: @What2107 Did you fix this issue? I am facing the same issue. Can you provide the answer?